# Finding the highest occuring element for a list within a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to create a method that will return the "bucket" that contains the most keys in this. For example

If I had a list of lists with this data

```
[['Smith', 17], ['Josh', 4], ['Steve', 19], ['Josh', 4], ['Josh', 4], ['Steve', 19]]
```

my method `LargestNumberBucket()` would return 3 since either the key or value appear 3 times.
My code is listed below:

```
class hashTable:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.hash = []

    def insertItem(self, key):
        sum = 0 
        for x in key:
            sum = sum + ord(x)
        newSum = sum % self.size
        self.hash.append([key, newSum]) #Using append makes it to where it uses linear probing

    def printTable(self):
            print(self.hash)


    def search(self, key):
        for searchedKey in self.hash:
            if (searchedKey[0] == key):
                print("The record", searchedKey, "was found.")
                break
        else:
            print("The item was not found")

    def deleteItem(self, key):
        sum = 0 
        for x in key:
            sum = sum + ord(x)
        newSum = sum % self.size

        self.hash.remove([key, newSum])

    def numberOfRecords(self):
        x = 0 
        while (x < len(self.hash)):
            x = x + 1
        print("The total number of records in the table are ", x)
#figure out how to count collisions and largest bucket  
    def numOfCollisions(self):
        for x in self.hash:
            y = self.hash.count(x)
        print("The number of collisions are", y)
#This does not work.
    def largestNumberBucket(self):
        print("The largest bucket contains",
              max(set(self.hash[1]), key=self.hash.count), "buckets")
```

Comment: So, what is your problem/question?

Comment: I'm trying to find the element that occurs the most from my list of lists. I cannot seem to figure out how to. My defLargestNumberBucket(self) method does not work the way i'd like it to, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: You should give a detailed description of the problem, including what you except and what you get instead, to the question.

Comment: cant you use `count` and do `max` of it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `Counter`. Let's consider this this quick example

Using zip, we build two tuples by selecting them from the same position.

```
a,b=zip(*d)
```

Output:

```
a==> ('Smith', 'Josh', 'Steve', 'Josh', 'Josh', 'Steve') 
b==> (17, 4, 19, 4, 4, 19)
```

Then, using a Counter, we find the frequency of items

```
Counter(a)
```

would give.

```
Counter({'Josh': 3, 'Steve': 2, 'Smith': 1})
```

Then we select, only values by using   `Counter(a).values()`:

```
[2, 3, 1]
```

and get the max

```
max(Counter(a).values())
```

We do the same thing for b, which is the list of values in second position. Then we select the max in both results

```
d= [['Smith', 17], ['Josh', 4], ['Steve', 19], ['Josh', 4], ['Josh', 4], ['Steve', 19]]

from collections import Counter
a,b=zip(*d)
print max(max(Counter(a).values()),max(Counter(b).values())) #Output:3
```

or

```
print max(Counter(a).values()+Counter(b).values()) #Output:3, as it's the max of the union
```

Your code would look like:

```
def largestNumberBucket(self):
  a,b=zip(*self.hash)
  #print("The largest bucket contains", max(max(Counter(a).values()),max(Counter(b).values())), "buckets")
  print("The largest bucket contains", max(Counter(a).values()+Counter(b).values()), "buckets")
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @nneonneo, We can get the max value using `Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][1]`

```
def largestNumberBucket(self):
  a,b=zip(*self.hash)
  print("The largest bucket contains", max(Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][1],Counter(b).most_common(1)[0][1]), "buckets")
```

Comment: You can skip a lot of the intermediate stuff by using `Counter(a).most_common()[0]`.

Comment: +1 @nneonneo You're right! I've updated the post. +Padraic I just followed the sequenced way to explain, but I suggested other ways as well to reduce the number of max.

Answer (score 0):

i have simply used `count` and `max`

```
>>> a = [['Smith', 17], ['Josh', 4], ['Steve', 19], ['Josh', 4], ['Josh', 4], ['Steve', 19]] 
>>> max(a.count(x) for x in a)
3
```

Comment: This is *really* inefficient: O(n^2) for a list of `n` elements.